# Laravel Data Converter

Tags: php, converters, laravel-5

I have a model that holds 7 digits as string. I want to create converter that the interaction between the user and that string will be like `##-###-##`. So if the model holds `1234567` the user will see `12-345-67` and if the user entered the number as `76-543-21` the model stores it like `7654321`.

Many other platforms are including converters to handle this kind of tasks. How can I do that in Laravel 5.2? I have searched in the docs and didn't find any helpful solution.

Is Laravel 5.2 support converters? And how should I handle such conversion?

Comment: Take a look at [accessors and mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Comment: Thanks, that exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Laravel supports "converters", actually they are called mutators.
Mutators can be defined as both setters and getters. Depending on how you wish to convert the values.

In your specific case you will need to use the setter and getter mutator, since you will convert the values before they are stored in your database and when they are read:

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Set the models name attribute.
     * @param  string  $value
     */
    public function setNameAttribute($value)
    {
        if ( /* do regex to check if the value that user has entered is already in the format ##-###-## */) {                
            $this->attributes['name'] = $value; // Already formatted, no need to do anything
        } else {
            $this->attributes['name'] = ....; // convert to correct format
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the models name attribute.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
     public function getNameAttribute($value)
     {
         return /* convert value to ##-###-## format */;
     }
}
```

You specify the mutator by naming your function `set[Column name]Attribute` and `get[Column name]Attribute` in camel case. So if your column name is for example `name`, then your mutator would be named `public funtion setNameAttribute($value)` and `public funtion getNameAttribute($value)`

Comment: Hmm, I want them to stored like `#######` in the database but the usage will be like `##-###-##`. BTW, in the link in Mark Baker comment, the function name should have `Attribute` at the end. So it need to be like `setNameAttribute`, right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was to quick on reading your question, I updated the anwer now, but I realize you have already received the answer from the documentation link provided in Marks comment

Comment: The regex test you could do on the string: `\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}` will be tested against `##-###-##`